# Can't uninstall AMD drivers

Tags: drivers, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall AMD drivers after my graphics card stopped working in normal mode in windows (it's still giving DVI output in safe mode). I seem to be unable to do so. I tried following the instructions on http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/pages/gpu57removeoldgraphicsdrivers.aspx but the uninstall button for my AMD software is grayed out. Any attempt to access the Installshield for uninstallation of AMD related services doesn't start up.

Next step I tried was to run an uninstaller/cleanup tool (from e.g. AMD but I've also tried third party ones). These simply don't start, and a "dead" process stays in my memory forever.

Let me know if you require additional information in the comments. Some specifics to my situation:

- It's a desktop PC that worked previously, but suddenly had issues with crashing graphics cards (another gpu, not the one I'm using now). Within two days of this, one SATA port for my HDD failed as well (and is still non-functional).
- I've installed another GPU (XFX Radeon 6800) and now it no longer gives gpu output after the first time the windows 10 graphic (the "flag") appears during windows startup.
- My system is (roughly) the Core i5-3570k, AMD Radeon 6800, Cooler Master M620, Gigabyte G3X-P77X (from the top of my head), and standard 16 GB corsair DDR3-1333 memory. I could not find compatibility issues for this combination of hardware.
- I'm running Windows 10, 64 bit.

Comment: http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/display_driver_uninstaller.html   This tool **ddu** has always worked for me.  The newest AMD drivers installer offers a **clean install** option.

Comment: I put it down as answer.  If it works mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

majorgeeks.com/files/details/display_driver_uninstaller.html This tool ddu has always worked for me. The newest AMD drivers installer offers a clean install option